Writing style: why is "in the context of" bad?
I am using a style checker http://www.cs.umd.edu/~nspring/software/style-check-readme.html and it scolds me for using "in the context of".

In the context of CUDA, this is also called managed memory.

Why is this wrong? What would be a better phrase?

Do the words "the context of" add any meaning to the sentence? I would also avoid using "this" to refer back to something unnamed in the current sentence.

@BryanKrause Yes, because it is called something else in different contexts

So? If it's called managed memory in CUDA, you can just say "In CUDA, (thing you are describing) is called managed memory." "In CUDA" means "In the context of CUDA". The extra words are superfluous.

The spell checker rule is in the ruleset verbose-phrases (which might give you a hint of why) and has an explanation: in the context of % phrase "in" avoid, if possible.

In CUDA, this is also called managed memory.

